# With the Sqlalchemy, trying to create a table in sql Database

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In my Python script I am using Sqlalchemy, after setting up a connection

```
connection = engine.connect()

data_gov=connection.execute("select * into temp from mytest_1 where FollowersOf ='gov'")
data=data_gov.fetchall()
```

But I cant see any table in my sql database and cant able to fetchall as well.Please help

Answer (score 0):

After lot of attempts, somehow I myself got the answer. So its following, engine.connect() just creates a proxy connection. So after Few tweaks only

```
connection = engine.raw_connection()
data_gov=connection.execute("select * into temp from mytest_1 where FollowersOf ='gov'").commit()
connection.close()
```

And, you will happily see a real table in your sql database, not just a proxy